# Made changes to previous release, now need to incorporate latest release into current branch (Git)

Tags: git, xcode6

**UPDATED** Sorry for this lame question, but I need some guidance: I have an iPad app I'm making major changes to on branch 3.2.0.  I received notification that the previous version 3.1.0 had a bug, so I switched to an existing branch (3.1.0) from 3.2.0, made the changes, created a new branch (3.1.1) and committed it (local and remote).  This is what it looks like now:

[image]

Now, I need to incorporate the changes made to 3.1.1 into 3.2.0 without farkeling anything up in 3.2.0.  I've read about *merging* and *rebasing*, but not sure which to use.

How do I do that from within XCode 6.1?

**UPDATE #2** So I did the 'git checkout 3.2.0' and the 'git cherry-pick 3.1.1' and this is what happened:

> iMac-2:salonbook rolfmarsh$ git checkout 3.2.0
>   2014-12-22 14:11:23.988 xcodebuild[21886:13545655] [MT] PluginLoading: Required plug-in compatibility UUID C4A681B0-4A26-480E-93EC-1218098B9AA0 for plug-in at path '~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin' not present in DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs
>   Already on '3.2.0'
>   iMac-2:salonbook rolfmarsh$ git cherry-pick 3.1.1
>   warning: Cannot merge binary files: ja.lproj/MainStoryboard.strings (HEAD vs. 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1)
>   warning: Cannot merge binary files: it.lproj/MainStoryboard.strings (HEAD vs. 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1)
>   warning: Cannot merge binary files: fr.lproj/MainStoryboard.strings (HEAD vs. 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1)
>   warning: Cannot merge binary files: es.lproj/MainStoryboard.strings (HEAD vs. 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1)
>   warning: Cannot merge binary files: en.lproj/MainStoryboard.strings (HEAD vs. 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1)
>   warning: Cannot merge binary files: de.lproj/MainStoryboard.strings (HEAD vs. 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1)
>   error: could not apply 012c66e... GR - 1.3.1
>   hint: after resolving the conflicts, mark the corrected paths
>   hint: with 'git add ' or 'git rm '
>   hint: and commit the result with 'git commit'

Now what do I do?  (I was afraid of something like this!) :-{

Comment: See https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/merging-vs-rebasing/ for merging vs rebasing difference.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe:  I updated the question with an image of what the branches look like now; based on the link you gave, it appears this is ripe for merging and not rebasing.  You agree?

Comment: Yes, rebasing is out of the question here since you have pushed the branches to remote already. But listen to the advice from @SzG in his answer. Use tags to mark a release, not branches.

Comment: You could either merge, or rebase, or cherry-pick. The choice is largely up to personal and/or project preference, although each option does have certain trade-offs...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to cherry-pick the commit with the fix.

```
git checkout 3.2.0
git cherry-pick 3.1.1
```

Unlike a merge, this will take the patch only from the specified commit, not the entire history since the two branches have diverged.

But how to do it from within Xcode? Ain't got no clue. Search Google for `Xcode git cherry-pick`. Except that in the 1st 2 hits it's `git add -p` what they call cherry picking. I'm at a loss here. Just use the command line. It's easy.

Upon conflicts, `git status` shows the conflicting files as `both modified`. Edit them, `git add` them and then `git commit`. Git remembers that this commit should finish the `cherry-pick`.

You practice of creating releases with branches is dangerous. That's what tags are for. Branches move with each commit on them. Tags stay.

Comment: OK... is there any way to recover if this farkels up 3.2.0?

Comment: SzG: isn't the *cherry-pick* command incorrect?  Shouldn't it be **cherry-pick 3.1.1**?

Comment: That was probably the correct answer, but it farkeled the branches, so I wound up doing it by hand... thanks for your time tho'.